# Removing key/value pairs in list of dictionary having None Values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

**inputs :** [{'test1': 'test', 'test2': None}]

**Exected output :** [{'test1': 'test'}]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to process the inputs that results in your expected output. It eliminates key: value pairs from dictionaries where the value is `None` then eliminates totally empty dictionaries from the list.

```
data = [{'test1': 'test', 'test2': None}]

output = [entry for entry in [{key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value != None} for dictionary in data] if len(entry)>0]
print(output)
```

EDIT: As per Itamar's comment below, you might want to maintain the original length of the list, for example in the case where you wanted to compare output from a consistent number of functions. Just eliminate the outermost digest:

```
data = [{'test1': 'test', 'test2': None}]

output = [{key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value != None} for dictionary in data]
print(output)
```

Comment: Do you need the check for `len(entry)>0`?

Comment: the outermost list digest is only to eliminate totally empty dictionaries from the list, ones that started with nothing but empty values. that's a good point, you might want to keep them around to maintain the consistency of a list of multiple functions' kwargs or something. i'll update the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired output using the list comprehension - [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
inputs = [{'test1': 'test', 'test2': None}]

output = [{k: v for k, v in var.items() if v is not None} for var in inputs]
print(output)
```

Result:

```
[{'test1': 'test'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keep_keys = set()

for d in inputs:
        for key, value in d.items():
                if value is not None:
                        keep_keys.add(key)

remove_keys = set(d) - keep_keys

for d in inputs:
        for k in remove_keys:
                del d[k]

print (inputs)
```

Comment: ... does this work? I see that `remove_keys` uses `d`, which is defined in a `for` loop - but is itself outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
myDict = {key:val for key,val in myDict.items() if val != None}
```

Comment: Note that the question has a list of dicts